# RequireJS'ing a jQuery plugin without a global $ variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, amd

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm trying to develop an app that doesn't create a global `$` or `jQuery` variable when loading in jQuery, but still works with some plugins that weren't developed with AMD in mind.

**main script**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min',
        somePlugin: 'vendor/somePlugin.min'
    },
    map: {
        '*': { jquery: 'secret-jquery' },
        'secret-jquery': { jquery: 'jquery' }
    },
    shim: {
        somePlugin: ['jquery']
    }
});
```

**secret-jquery.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

Unfortunately, it sets up the jQuery plugin like so:

**somePlugin.min.js**

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function (options) {
    // ...
});
```

I don't need the shim if I change the plugin source to use `define`, i.e.

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $.fn.somePlugin = function (options) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

But that breaks the rule of not modifying third-party plugins, especially popular plugins that I might later swap out with an updated version.

I *cannot* use a global `$` or `jQuery` variable because my script needs to inject jQuery onto a page that may already have loaded it (and consequently loaded a different version with an incompatible API, and my jQuery can't break anything on the page).

Is there a clean way to do this, or is the best way to just change the plugin code? I can't think of any other way to do it, save loading in the script via an XMLHttpRequest, wrapping it with a `define` call, and `eval`ing it, which seems like it'd defeat the purpose of letting RequireJS take care of the dirty work.

Comment: Never `eval`. Have you tried doing `wrapShim: true` ?

Comment: My solution would be to wrap the plugin in an immediately invoked function expression... `(function($) { ... /* plugin code */ ... })(jQuery)`

Comment: @Tomanow Is that a pre-build step? I'm not using the optimizer, I probably should but I haven't set up a server yet. So I take it that would wrap the plugin in a define call automatically during the build process?

Comment: > This will wrap shimmed dependencies in a define() call so that they work better after a build when their upstream dependencies are also AMD modules with dependencies.

Comment: So it sounds like the only solution is to either manually or automatically end up wrapping it in a define call then

Comment: OR if you are concerned about updating in the future, why not contact the plugin developer and ask him to fix? Sometimes a very simple solution!

Comment: It'd be ideal if the developer confirmed, but it's a paid plugin built by a company team of developers, so while I might suggest it, I doubt they'd change their approach. I'll probably add the `define` call myself for now and keep a todo to implement `wrapShim` along with other build steps like uglifying JS when I'm at that point. Thanks for your advice though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How we're doing this is that we're defining our secret-jquery.js like so:

```
define(['jquery', 'vendor/somePlugin.min'], function (jQuery) {
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

With our config looking like:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min',
        somePlugin: 'vendor/somePlugin.min'
    },
    map: {
        '*': { jquery: 'secret-jquery' },
        'secret-jquery': { jquery: 'vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min' }
    },
    shim: {
        somePlugin: ['jquery']
    }
});
```

This has given us the least amount of problems with jQuery plugins that do not use RequireJS while still allowing us to take advantage of RequireJS in our own code. Sure, we aren't keeping track of which jQuery plugins a piece of code uses, but in my opinion, jQuery plugins are not usually developed to make this easy anyway since, even when they are able to use RequireJS, they don't normally return anything and instead extend jQuery itself.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand this: assuming another version of jQuery is loaded... this would (1) load my version of jQuery in as a global; (2) extend $.fn with somePlugin; (3) call noConflict, restoring the original jQuery version to global, meaning original won't have somePlugin; (4) my secret jQuery version is now totally confined to my modules. The only downside being `secret-jquery.js` loads all plugins, instead of the plugin requirements being defined by the modules that use them. If this is correct, perfect -- I only have a few plugins and I need them all for core functionality.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Like I said, I wish that jQuery plugins didn't extend the jQuery global, but since they do, this approach seems to balance the pros and cons correctly.

Comment: In the first line of secret-jquery.js, should `define` accept `'somePlugin'` instead of `'vendor/somePlugin.min'`, since the path is defined in the config?

Comment: An issue I discovered is that occasionally it finishes the request to `vendor/somePlugin.min` first, in which case it throws an error saying `jQuery is undefined`. Is there a different approach that requires jQuery to load first?